# ion-list with checkbox disable in ionic framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Here is my **[Codepen](http://codepen.io/skpatel/pen/xGBjPx)**.

In this demo application I have two list arrays. One is `items` and second is `items1`.

I want to:

1. show list as such that where some items from `items` array should be pre-checked which are in `items1`.
2. I do not want user to check and uncheck. So that means checkbox should be disabled.

How can I do that with the demo Codepen I shared earlier. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did I understand you right? Are you looking for this? [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbGYWb?editors=101)

Comment: @AndersRehn thanks, Let me check.

Comment: @AndersRehn can you please explain me as a answer below I will accept it soon. Thanks again

Comment: @sam_k he did the same thing as answer given by Vamsi V

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to `ng-init` to set the value of `item.checked` on input `init`

```
ng-init="item.checked = (items1|filter: {id: item.id})[0].id == item.id;"
```

[**Working Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPJKPJ?editors=101)

Comment: I can able to select checkbox, that should be disable and list item click should be work

Comment: I think I should use ng-disabled='true'.

Comment: @sam_k but that seems clering the `ng-model` value

Comment: So how can i do this? Actually I wanted to show list of items where some are selected which has been visited by user. Others items are clickable and able to open new page where item details would be display

Comment: waiting for your answer too

Comment: @sam_k didn't find any working thing.still searching

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86715/discussion-between-sam-k-and-pankaj-parkar).

Comment: Can you please take a look on this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31975132/open-new-page-when-user-click-on-any-item-from-ion-item

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how dynamically you want to set the pre-checked items you can do one of the following.

## Disable user-click

Depending whether you want that grey or blue checkbox you either do

### Blue checkbox

change

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-click=" $event.stopPropagation();" ng-model="item.checked">
```

to

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleItem(item) $event.stopPropagation();" ng-model="item.checked">
```

Basically removing the click function that will set a checked value for the item.

### Grey checkbox

Just disable the `<input>` element using the attribute `disabled` like this `<input type="checkbox" disabled>`

## Case 1: your items always stays the same (you create the items)

For each matching item in `$scope.items` and `$scope.items1`you add a key called `checked:true` to the matching items.
In your case that would be to create the arrays as following

```
$scope.items1 = [
    { id: 1 },
    { id: 2 },
    { id: 3 },
    { id: 9 },
    { id: 10 }
  ];

  $scope.items = [
    { id: 1, checked:true },
    { id: 2, checked:true },
    { id: 3, checked:true },
    { id: 4 },
    { id: 5 },
    { id: 6 },
    { id: 7 },
    { id: 8 },
    { id: 9, checked:true },
    { id: 10, checked:true }
 ];
```

## Case 2: dynamically find matching items based on their id

```
$scope.items1 = [
    { id: 1 },
    { id: 2 },
    { id: 3 },
    { id: 9 },
    { id: 10 }
];

$scope.items = [
    { id: 1},
    { id: 2},
    { id: 3},
    { id: 4 },
    { id: 5 },
    { id: 6 },
    { id: 7 },
    { id: 8 },
    { id: 9},
    { id: 10}
];

for(var i=0; i<$scope.items.length; i++){
    for(var k=0; k<$scope.items1.length; k++){
      if($scope.items[i].id == $scope.items1[k].id){ 
         $scope.items[i].checked = true;
         break;
      }
    }    
}
```